# Maximum interval of definition of solution of ODE

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, analysis

I'm studying first order ODEs, and I have the following theorem:

> Let
> $$
> \left\{
> \begin{aligned}
> y' &= f(y, t) \\ 
> y(t_0) &= y_0
> \end{aligned}
> \right.
> \tag{1}
> $$
> with $(t_0, y_0)\in D\subset\mathbb{R}$ and $D$ an open set, be a Cauchy problem for a first order ODE, for which existence and unicity of the solution is granted in a neighborhood $I$ of $t_0$. Then the solution is defined in a "maximal interval" $(t_{\mathrm{min}}, t_{\mathrm{max}})$. Outside this interval, the solution isn't defined or is outside $D$.

Now, my problem with this theorem is that I don't understand what is the purpose of finding this interval where a solution is defined, and I'll articulate it in two points:

1. What does the theorem mean for "definition" of a solution $\phi(t)$? Does it really mean "where the analytical expression of the $\phi(t)$ is defined" or does it mean "where the function $\phi(t)$ found is also a solution"? Because in the second case, it could be that $\phi(t)$ is defined in a subset of $\mathbb{R}$ which is bigger than the subset made by the $t\in D$ for which $\phi(t)$ is a solution for $(1)$
2. Why do we even care about the solution $\phi(t)$, except from in $(t_0, y_0)$, where we are solving the Cauchy problem? My guess is that if the solution found for the Cauchy problem $y(t_0)=y_0$ is defined in an interval $I$, then the theorem says that for each $t_1\in(t_{\mathrm{min}}, t_{\mathrm{max}})$, $\phi(t)$ is a solution of the Cauchy problem $y(t_1)=\phi(t_1)$ (for the same ODE of $(1)$)

**IN ANOTHER WORDS**

The pair $(t_0, y_0)$, because of the uniqueness of the solution to the Cauchy problem $(1)$, "identifies" a function $\phi _1(t)$, and now that we found it we can write the pair as $(t_0, \phi _1(t_0))$. This solution is a function which will have the $c \in \mathbb{R}$ parameter fixed, because of the second equation in the Cauchy problem.

My question is: which of the following two problems are we approaching with the theorem?

1. We're trying to find the biggest interval (on the t-axis), that contains $t_0$, for which the solution to $(1)$ is still THE SAME $\phi _1(t)$, and that means that the pair that identifies the Cauchy problems for each $t$ in the maximal interval is of type $(t, \phi _1(t))$
2. We're trying to find the biggest interval (on the t-axis), that contains $t_0$, for which the solution to $(1)$ exists and is unique, but it can be a function $\phi _2(t) \neq \phi _1(t)$, and thus we're moving the y-axis "freely" without the $y=\phi _1(t)$ constraint

Comment: As for 2., sometimes you don't want to bother keeping track of the domain of definition of a particular solution of an IVP. Keep in mind that the Existence theorem for IVPs is usually stated as "this or that IVP admits a solution $ y\colon I\to \mathbb R^n $ defined on _some_ interval $ I $". But this doesn't mean that if you take some bigger $ J\supset I $ then you cannot extend $ y $ as to have again a function that solves your IVP.

Comment: Consider $y'(x) = \sec^2(x), y(0)=0$.  There is only one solution to the differential equation on any (small enough) open interval containing $x = 0$.  We need not worry about a second solution through the same initial condition.  What there is *not* is a solution on the interval $(-\pi,\pi)$.  The only solution is undefined at $\pm \pi/2$ (i.e., at the vertical asymptotes), so cannot be extended to a larger interval.  If you, for some reason, need a solution at $x = 100$, you will have to find initial data somewhere in a small enough interval containing $x=100$.

Comment: @EricTowers thanks, I think your example made it clearer to me. So we don't care at all about the fact that there might be other solutions for other $y_0$ defined in a bigger interval containing $x_0$ than ours. Our solution is fixed. Only note that I think  your example might be not enough "general", since the solution of the ODE is $\phi_1(x)=tan(x)+c$ and thus the "$+c$" part doesn't impact on the definition of the solution: if the initial condition is $y(x_0=0)=y_0$ the solution will always be defined maximum in $(-\pi /2, +\pi /2)$ for every $y_0$. I'm pointing that out because I was...

Comment: ...wondering what happens if, for example, the solution was $\phi (x, c)=\frac{1}{x+c}$ and $x_0=1$. Then it's clear that if $y_0$ is such that $c=0$, $\phi _1(x)=\frac{1}{x}$ cannot be defined on a bigger interval than $(0, ?)$. Otherwise, by choosing another $y_0$ such that $c=1$ for example, we have that $\phi _2(x)=\frac{1}{x+1}$ might be defined on a bigger interval $(-1, ?)$. But again, as you said, we don't care about that, since if we consider $\phi(x)$ with $c$ fixed we stick with that function-solution, so all good

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not a question of an "analytical expression": there's no guarantee that a closed-form expression for the solution exists at all.  You simply want to find the largest interval in which this Cauchy problem has a solution. Typically, as $t$ approaches an endpoint of such an interval, $(t, y(t))$ might approach a point where the function $f(y,t)$ is undefined or discontinuous, or $y(t)$ might go off to $\pm \infty$.

Comment: Ok, so what we do is that we fix the function $\phi(t)$ found as a solution of the Cauchy problem $(t_0, y_0=\phi (t_0))$ and "move" $t$, so that the whole $(t, y(t))$ that identifies the Cauchy problem moves , correct? Because if we fix the $t_0$ and choose a different $y_1\neq y_0$, then the solution found for $(t_0, y_1)$ should be different (in general) to $\phi (t)$ found before, and thus the "maximum interval" question makes no sense, correct?

Comment: BTW, I'm aware that there might be no closed form expression, I'm sorry I used the wrong words. I just wanted to highlight the fact that my problem was understanding if the theorem was trying to find just the interval of definition of the function-solution without caring if it's still a solution of the Cauchy problem, OR if it was trying to find for which other couples $(t, y(t))$ the function found as a solution is still a solution. I would be glad if you could solve me this doubt.

Comment: It's simply this.  There are some intervals $(a,b)$ containing $t_0$ such that your Cauchy problem has a solution defined for $t \in (a,b)$.  There may be other intervals such that there is no such solution defined for $t \in (a,b)$.  The theorem is saying that there is some $(a_m, b_m)$ (where $a_m$ could be $-\infty$ and $b_m$ could be $+\infty$) such that there is a solution defined for $t \in (a_m, b_m)$ but there is no solution defined on any interval strictly containing $(a_m, b_m)$.

Comment: I edited the question and tried to explain it in another words, which hopefully will make the question clearer. If you have the patience to have a look at the question I would appreciate it.

Comment: As far as you know, $\phi_1(t)$ is only defined for $t \in I$.  You want a solution $\phi$ defined on a larger interval $(a_m, b_m)$.  Of course $\phi(t) = \phi_1(t)$ for $t \in I$.